# Pywin32 click on excel sheet button

Tags: excel, python-3.x, pywin32

I have a excel sheet with two buttons:

[image: Example]

Both buttons starts the same macro called MyMacroExample with its respectives parameters, but we do not have access to it, so we can not know what are the parameters each button pass to the macro. We need a way to click on each button so the macro can be acatived with the correct parameter.

Currently we are using Pywin32 with the follwing code:

```
sheet.Application.Run('MyMacroExample')
```

But since **we do not know what are the parameters and do not have access to macro script** we need to click on each button. How can we do that using python or more specifically pywin32?